# Set SSL options in PHP (which work at the prompt)

Tags: php, ssl, openssl

At the prompt I can successfully establish an SSL connection using:

```
openssl s_client -connect 10.1.2.3:4 -key /path/to/foo.pem -CAfile /path/to/cert.pem
```

How can I create this same connection with `stream_socket_client()` ?

I have:

```
$context = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '/path/to/foo.pem');
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'cafile', '/path/to/cert.pem');
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', true);
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);

$socket = stream_socket_client('ssl://10.1.2.3:4', $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
```

But this yields:

```
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): Unable to set local cert chain file
```

Obviously I'm not using the right settings, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Chain file would suggest the path is wrong to `cert.pem`. Either that, or your PHP script doesn't have permissions to read it.

Comment: I'd assume so, but it's the same path that works for the `openssl` command, and there's definitely a private key file at that path that I can access.